# Align textview and spinner on same row

Tags: android

I want to align my textview and spinner on the same row like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMNRp.jpg) but my screen looks like [this](http://imgur.com/9TH2l)

Also how can I update price textview with the spinner's value? Suppose that the product price is $200, when I select 2 on spinner textview change to $400. How do I do that?

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="#E5E5E5"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="Qty"
        android:textSize="10pt"></TextView>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/SpinnerFeedbackType"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:entries="@array/feedbacktypelist"></Spinner>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextName"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"></EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextEmail"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"></EditText>
     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextMobile"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:hint="Mobile Number"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"></EditText>
      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditCity"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:hint="City"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"></EditText>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextFeedbackBody"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:hint="Address"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"></EditText>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextComments"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:hint="Comments"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"></EditText>


     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="Total Order Price:"
        android:textSize="10pt"></TextView>



     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="Rs.6,849"
        android:textSize="10pt"></TextView>





    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/CheckBoxResponse"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/feedbackresponse"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"></CheckBox>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonSendFeedback"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/feedbackbutton"
        android:onClick="sendFeedback"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Button>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put spinner and text view in horizontal linear layout.

Implement spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener). and change the TextView text as you need.

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
 {

   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3)

    {         
              String txtNo=textView.getText().toString().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
              textView.setText(Integer.parseInt(Spinner.getSelectedItem().toString())*
              Integer.parseInt(txtNo));
    }

  });
```

Comment: telll me full senario whe spinner sleect how will its number multiply price??

Comment: is show error  java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'Rs.6,849' as integer

Comment: its show error  java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'Rs.6,849' as integer

Comment: please remove comma and try.

Comment: problem is i didnot remove it its come form server

Comment: then extract only numbers from the string.

Comment: i think this will help you.- String numberOne= str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

Comment: The method replaceAll(String, String) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments ()

Comment: put like this "[^0-9]" (double quotes)

Comment: this post help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676029/my-code-doesnt-multiply-value-of-stirng-with-integer

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are using orientation as vertical on the parent layout.And you have not given any parentLayout to the set of Views you want to show horizontally.
Put the two textview and spinner in a LinearLayout with orientation as horizontal

Try the below data :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="Qty"
        android:textSize="10pt"></TextView>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/SpinnerFeedbackType"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:weight=".5"
        android:entries="@array/feedbacktypelist"></Spinner>
</LinearLayout>
```

Do calculation in your setOnItemSelectedListener

```
priceTextView.setText(Integer.parseInt(Spinner.getSelectedItem().toString())*
              Integer.parseInt(productPrice));
```

Considering your productPrice is String

Comment: but i want to display same like sample image which i attect above

Comment: The above data will give your desired image layout

Answer (score 3):

Make xml like this , this will solve your issue

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="#E5E5E5"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"

>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="Qty"
        android:textSize="10pt"></TextView>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/SpinnerFeedbackType"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:entries="@array/feedbacktypelist"></Spinner>

</LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextName"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"></EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextEmail"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"></EditText>
     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextMobile"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:hint="Mobile Number"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"></EditText>
      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditCity"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:hint="City"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"></EditText>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextFeedbackBody"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:hint="Address"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"></EditText>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextComments"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:hint="Comments"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"></EditText>


     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="Total Order Price:"
        android:textSize="10pt"></TextView>



     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="Rs.6,849"
        android:textSize="10pt"></TextView>





    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/CheckBoxResponse"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/feedbackresponse"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"></CheckBox>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonSendFeedback"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/feedbackbutton"
        android:onClick="sendFeedback"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Button>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them into a linear layout of horizontal orientation, like this...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dd"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="Qty"
        android:textSize="10pt" >
    </TextView>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/SpinnerFeedbackType"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >
    </Spinner>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your current vertical layout, wrap the textview and spinner with a LinearLayout that has horizontal orientation.

as for your second question, you would simply multiply the price by the number in your quantity field, which can be obtained from mySpinner.getSelectedItem() and cast it as needed.